# Updating Data in DataGridView?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to update data from datagrid view back to the SQL server, and i get an error

" Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index "

My Code is as bellow , any help would be appreciated

```
Try
        SQLConnection = New MySqlConnection()
        SQLConnection.ConnectionString = connstr
        SQLConnection.Open()

        Console.WriteLine("MySQL version : {0}", SQLConnection.ServerVersion)
        SQL = ""
        For J = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            SQL = SQL & " UPDATE `ntechtbs`.`a2sbkgsys` SET `NumberOfPax`='" & DataGridView1.Item(J, 1).Value & "', `PAXName`='" & DataGridView1.Item(J, 2).Value & "',`Origin`='" & 
                DataGridView1.Item(J, 3).Value & "',`Destination`='" & DataGridView1.Item(J, 4).Value & "', `Services`='" & DataGridView1.Item(J, 5).Value & "',`ArrivalDate`='" & DataGridView1.Item(J, 6).Value & "',`DepartureDate`='" & DataGridView1.Item(J, 7).Value & "',`BookingReference`='" & DataGridView1.Item(J, 8).Value & "',`Status`='" & DataGridView1.Item(J, 9).Value & "',`PriceQuote`='" & DataGridView1.Item(J, 10).Value & "',`AgencyPin`='" & DataGridView1.Item(J, 11).Value & "',`AgentPin`='" & DataGridView1.Item(J, 12).Value & "',`SIPCODE`='" & DataGridView1.Item(J, 13).Value & _
                "WHERE ID=" & DataGridView1.Item(J, 0).Value & ";"
        Next
        MsgBox(SQL)

        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(SQL, SQLConnection)

        Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If (i > 0) Then
            MsgBox("Record is Successfully Updated")
        Else
            MsgBox("Record is not Updated")
        End If
        SQLConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Can you post the code that populates your DataGridView? How many columns are there in your DataGridView?

Comment: I have 14 Columns in my Data Grid View @Andrea